# why it is creating array new array while making json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a json array after watching a json array .I am facing one problem it create array inside the object .but I need to add array inside the parent array
I am getting this result

```
[
  {
    "a": {
      "commandList": [],
      "testCaseList": []
    },
    "testCaseList": []
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "commandList": [],
      "testCaseList": []
    },
    "testCaseList": [
      {
        "b-a-1": {
          "commandList": [],
          "testCaseList": []
        },
        "testCaseList": []
      },
      {
        "b-b-2": {
          "commandList": [],
          "testCaseList": []
        },
        "testCaseList": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "c-1": {
      "commandList": [],
      "testCaseList": []
    },
    "testCaseList": []
  }
]
```

But I need to get this out put

```
[
  {
    "a": {
      "commandList": [

      ],
      "testCaseList": [

      ]
    },

  },
  {
    "b": {
      "commandList": [

      ],
          "testCaseList": [
      {
        "b-a-1": {
          "commandList": [

          ],
          "testCaseList": [

          ]
        },

      },
      {
        "b-b-2": {
          "commandList": [

          ],
          "testCaseList": [

          ]
        },

      }
    ]
    },

  },
  {
    "c-1": {
      "commandList": [

      ],
      "testCaseList": [

      ]
    },

  }
]
```

I try to change this line

```
 item.testCaseList = inputItem.children.map(mapItem);
```

to change

```
var obj= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.id)
obj.testCaseList=inputItem.children.map(mapItem)
```

Then I am getting error

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Kq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line you tried to change, Use

```
item[inputItem.id].testCaseList
```

instead of

```
item.testCaseList
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Kq/3/).

Try visualizing the data if it gets too messy. http://jsonblob.com/

Comment: I guess, someone failed to understand your question. Don't worry about it.